# past perfect unnecessary usage

Tags: past-perfect, past-simple

> In the afternoon, he'd attended a funeral.

What's the meaning of **"he'd attended"**?

Is it *"he had attended"*?! if so then why should we use past perfect instead of simple past?

Is it *"he would attended"*? What is this structure? I am not familiar with it.

Comment: so why we should use past perfect I cannot understand

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the past perfect.

The speaker is using the past perfect for the past perfect meaning. The funeral is before the time which is being discussed. The full context would probably give some reason:

> In the afternoon he'd attended a funeral. So when he sat down for dinner he was in a sombre mood.

The writer is talking about the time when he ate dinner, and the funeral preceded that, hence the past perfect.

Answer (score 2):

We use the simple form of the verb after *would* and the past participle of the verb after *had*, so here **'d** stands for **had** not *would*.

About your second question, there is nothing wrong with using past perfect in this sentence.  The point is that your sentence is probably not complete and there should be more information to show that this event has happened before another.

For example:

> When he came to visit us in the evening, we knew that he had attended the funeral in the afternoon.

Comment: In the afternoon he 'd attended a funeral. So when he sat down  for dinner he was in a sombre mood.   Past perfect is not obligatory because first action is attended then sat so it is crystal clear.

Comment: @user5577 It seems that your comment is related to James's answer, not mine.

Comment: oh you are right